# Conda Environment Has Two Pythons Installed

Tags: ubuntu, conda, pytorch

I followed the install instructions for PyTorch 1.0, in a Conda environment called `pytorch1`:

```
(pytorch1) me@comp:~$ conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

It claimed to be a successful install, and the log showed `pytorch-1.0.1` and `python-3.7.2`, but when I opened `ipython` I encountered the following:

```
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 17:14:51) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import torch
In [2]: torch.__version__
Out[2]: '0.4.1.post2'
```

Which is, of course, the wrong version of PyTorch.

I can open `python3.7` and the correct PyTorch is installed:

```
(pytorch1) me@comp:~$ python3.7
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 29 2018, 06:19:36) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.0.1.post2'
```

I'd like to use PyTorch with my current Jupyter notebook setup. Is there a way to get this working so that when I open iPython in the `pytorch1` environment, I can `import torch` to make version 1 available?

---

**UPDATE**: I updated Anaconda and now the Python version is right but iPython can't find PyTorch

Comment: `conda install ipython` in the conda environment you are using should fix this?

Comment: @UmangGupta That worked -- I really appreciate it. If you put that in an answer I'll mark it "best answer"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `ipython` you are using is installed using `python3.6` and outside the `conda` environment. You can use `which ipython` to see where it is located and guess if it is installed with system python or conda.

If it is installed using system python you can just install `ipython` with `conda` using `conda install ipython` in the conda environment. That should fix this.